# How to sum section of a column by date with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do I sum sections of a column by date, for example in this case, first from 2000 to 2008, and then 2009 to 2016?

```
    Date  Total Managed Expenditure
0   2001                      503.2
1   2002                      529.9
2   2003                      559.8
3   2004                      593.2
4   2005                      629.5
5   2006                      652.1
6   2007                      664.3
7   2008                      688.2
8   2009                      732.0
9   2010                      759.2
10  2011                      769.2
11  2012                      759.8
12  2013                      760.6
13  2014                      753.3
14  2015                      757.6
15  2016                      753.9
```

Comment: You can bin the years (convert them into a categorical variable) with `pd.cut` and then group by categories with `your_dataframe.groupby()`.

Comment: Your question is a little bit misleading. I think your should clarify if 2000 to 2008 actually means `2000-01-01` to `2008-01-01` or `2000-01-01` to `2009-01-01`. If you actually want the `sum` for every 8 year period, you should probably say that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `pandas.cut` to categorize, and then `groupby`:

**Code:**

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.Date, [2000, 2008, 2016]))['TME'].sum()
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
    u"""
    Date  TME
    2001  503.2
    2002  529.9
    2003  559.8
    2004  593.2
    2005  629.5
    2006  652.1
    2007  664.3
    2008  688.2
    2009  732.0
    2010  759.2
    2011  769.2
    2012  759.8
    2013  760.6
    2014  753.3
    2015  757.6
    2016  753.9"""
), header=1)\

print(df.groupby(pd.cut(df.Date, [2000, 2008, 2016]))['TME'].sum())
```

**Results:**

```
Date
(2000, 2008]    4820.2
(2008, 2016]    6045.6
Name: TME, dtype: float64
```

Comment: `[-np.inf, 2008, np.inf]` ensures that the script does not break any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen's answer is better. But I like this

```
df.groupby(df.Date.le(2008)).TME.sum()
```

Comment: @StephenRauch that's gross btw ;-)